# Is it non-constructive to tell a user without the comment privilege to leave a comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since acquiring the review privileged I've noticed a lot of users posting the following comment on poor answers:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

On its own, that would be fine. However most of the time this is left for new users without the 50 reputation required to leave a comment, and not on their own question. As they are unable to leave a comment, surely this is a non-constructive comment?

It appears that this is an automated response which can be made by using the review queue, so perhaps this comment could only be automatically posted when a user is actually able to comment (i.e. it's their own question or they have more than 50 reputation).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173

Comment: Is it inappropriate to tell someone they shouldn't steal cars just because they don't have enough money to buy their own?

Comment: @Servy While I agree with the sentiment;  if you can see that they don't have any money, it's fine to tell them not to steal one, but it's not very helpful to suggest they just buy one, which is what "leave a comment below their post" is like.  (Granted, it is followed by "once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post".  But still, that's like "don't steal one, buy one.  Eventually you'll be able to afford it.")  That said, it's easy enough to accumulate 50 rep that to "wait till you can afford it" isn't very hard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is entirely constructive -- it says "**once you have sufficient reputation** you will be able to comment on any post" (emphasis mine). It's not okay to do the wrong thing just because you aren't capable of doing the right thing, and this comment lets the user know what he needs to do to gain that ability.

Answer (score 11):

If they can't leave a comment, that's their problem not ours. If they don't have an answer, they shouldn't post an answer. The comment helps them learn what is and isn't an answer.

Answer (score -3):

You simply can't get around the fact that sometimes, a user without the required reputation (such as myself), may be able to answer a specific question, but requires more information do to so. For instance, someone may ask the question "How can I change the contents of a DOM element with JS", and not give any source code, hence leaving the answerer to guess at the method he should use to identify the DOM element (class, id, type or so on). This cannot be asked in an answer, as it does not answer the question, and can not be asked in a comment, as the answerer is unable to post comments. In this case, it actually becomes your problem, @bjb568, as your question will then go unanswered.

Therefore, one might argue that it is non-constructive **to disallow any legitimate user from posting comments**.

Comment: *"may be able to answer a specific question, but requires more information do to so"* Forgive me for being overly pedantic, but I'm pretty sure that means you **cannot** answer the question. No one can; there is not enough information provided. These types of questions should be closed (or flagged, if you don't have close-vote privileges) to prevent people from posting speculative answers that will become irrelevant once the question is updated with the necessary details. All of that being a roundabout way of saying: you can't comment, **but you can flag**.

Comment: This is a (hypothetical) drawback SO has accepted time and again; even external subject experts' clarifications are not considered important enough to justify trying to weed them out from everyone else wanting to drop irrelevant comments.

Comment: @CodyGray: Note that Bjonnfesk cannot flag either just yet, being 9 short.

Comment: Ugh, *one* good answer gets you 10 points. Post two of them are you're there. If you haven't yet posted two answers, you really aren't even interacting with the site, so this is all kind of a moot point.

Comment: Well... I don't think the point of whether the user has _previously_ interacted with the site is debatable at all, obviously, if they have less reputation than required, they haven't. However, I am sure we all agree that the past is no indication of the future, and being able to answer a question through getting more information as the result of a comment may _cause_ the user to be able to post two good answers, which would then allow them to comment. You must admit that there is a feasible Gordian Knot scenario here.

Comment: Also, @CodyGray, not being able to answer the question with the _current information_ does not equal being unable to answer the question. That is like saying that because I ask you the unanswerable question "What is two plus unspecified number", you are unable to answer the question if I specify the previously unspecified number. Sometimes, the asker of the question does not realise that more information is required to answer the question. Forgive me for being overly pedantic.

Comment: I *can't* answer that question. No one can. It's not a valid question. Not until that information gets added. That's why the question should be closed.

Comment: You continue to quite exceptionally miss the point. The question _can_ be answered if the required information is provided, this can be achieved by asking for it in a comment, and a lot of the time the asker may not even know that the information is relevant (hence they did not provide it). As the purpose of this website is to learn, I think it is bad manners to decide that a question is not worth answering because the asker did not have the knowledge needed to ask the question in the way _you_ consider correct, with all relevant information attached. They should get a chance to add it.

Comment: @Bjonnfesk They do get multiple chances to add it. Once, when they write the question; there is every opportunity to proofread your question to make sure it is answerable. Second, when **other** people comment on it. Trust me, if you see there's info lacking, someone else will too. Finally, if the question is closed by the required number of users, the OP *can still edit the question to get it into shape*. Please take a look at the help section, where all of this is explained, in great detail.